# Prevent page from scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a little problem with jQuery Mobile and anchor link's by url.

When page is load, after jquery throw event's work fine, but then jquery execute code and move page to top of page.
*my problem is not linking anchor in same page, is link another page with anchor with url, for example: `example_jquery.html#wopwop`

I write a little example for see isn't work (you can test in any browser):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <h1>wopwop</h1>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <a id="wopwop"></a>
        <h1>wopwop</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I write a patch looking post's in stackoverflow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(location.hash  == "#wopwop"){
      $.mobile.silentScroll($('#wopwop').get(0).offsetTop);
    }
  }, 700);
</script>
```

But i don't think is solution, do you know  how to make this work?.

Thx.
Sorry for my poor english

Comment: you need to execute the code on `pagecontainershow`. wrap it in `$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () { setTimeout.... });`.

Comment: @Omar mi dude is not make this work, it's make anchor link work with jquery-mobile. Thx for edit.

Comment: hombre, no lo entiendo, que quieres exactamente?

Comment: si pruebas el ejemplo, te fijaras que cuando cargas `example_jquery.html#wopwop` con jquery-mobile, primero baja al anchor, y despues sube al top de la pagina. 
Hice el parche para que despues de subir al top bajase, pero lo que no entiendo es porque jquery-mobile inutilza de esa manera los anchor links (supongo que porque los usa para enlazar pages).

Comment: that's why I told you to execute your code on `pagecontainershow`. When page is shown, jQM scrolls to top of page, you need to execute the code after jQM scrolls to top. Prueba `$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () { setTimeout.... });`

Comment: yes, i know this path and work, but i want link without efect of down-up and down in page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48273/discussion-between-omar-and-fermin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of jQuery Mobile when showing pages is to scroll to top upon showing a page. The value of scroll is always `0` and stored in `$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll`.

You need to override this value on any *page event* but before page is totally shown and transition is done.

```
if (location.hash == "#wopwop") { 
  $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll = $('#wopwop').offset().top; 
}
```

This will force scrolling to `wopwop` div's offset in page without scrolling to top and then back to that div.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#wopwop").offset().top }, 7000);
});
```

Comment: It's the same patch i wrote, don't think is a solution. Thx

Comment: Your div with id wopwop should NOT be empty. Fill it with just an empty  space or with text and will be ok!

<a id="wopwop">Some text here maybe</a>

Comment: R0ger if you use `example_jquery.html#wopwop` you can see in  this example page down - up  and then execute js and down page. I want fix it. Thx.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#wopwop").offset().top }, 1000);
        });        
    </script>
This worked for me