# JQuery Mobile transition stops working on long page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with page transitions no longer occuring when run from the bottom of a long page.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WVHA/7/

If you open up the example and click on the black navigation button the transition runs as expected. However if you return to the long page, scroll to the bottom and run it again the transition no longer occurs and the second page just appears straight away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div data-role="page" id="long">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Long Page</h1>
        <a href="#short" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-theme="b">DO TRANSITION</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 1</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 2</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 3</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 4</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 5</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 6</div>
        <div class="box">TEST BOX 7</div>        
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="short">
    <div id="gridheader" class="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Short Page</h1>
        <a href="#long" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" data-theme="b"> Back</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        Short page
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior of jQuery Mobile on long pages, transition animation is disabled.

You can solve this by scrolling to top of page on `pagebeforechange`.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, $.mobile.defaultHomeScroll);
});
```

[`$.mobile.defaultHomeScroll`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/f1049e5b6afda4e0183370365dcfedd8cd995f3f/js/init.js#L156) is `0` by default, unless *url bar* is hidden depending on device/platform.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3sVRL/)**

Comment: This is the better solution. Mucking about with the `getMaxScrollForTransition` could cause issues so I've removed my answer.

Comment: @ChrisHardie You should keep your answer, it contains an official reference to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Omar. I'll use your solution and try to add functionality to record the view position before the transition so I can scroll back down to it on return.

Comment: @user1898327 in this case, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988622/prevent-page-from-scrolling-to-top/21989837#21989837) could be of help.