# jQuery Mobile transition doesn't work with big content on the page?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am experiencing a problem, when using jqm on Phonegap app. The `data-transition="slide"` for example works fine, when the content of the page is not scrollable, but when the content is bigger, the animation doesn't apply. Any workarounds for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say the content is bigger, what do you mean? Scrolling vertically? horizontally? both?

Comment: I mean vertically - the content fills the whole screen and there is more content below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24451023/1771795